# 502 Bad gateway after deploying react app on GCP

Tags: reactjs, docker, google-cloud-platform, create-react-app, package.json

I recently upgraded my application from CRA-ts to CRA, upgraded react version from 16 to 17 with typescript version of 4.1 and node version to 16. On backend I still use node 8. When I deploy my app and try to access url, I get this error:

```
502 Bad Gateway - ngix
```

I checked GAE logs and ran a query for upstream I got this:

```
[error]: upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client...
```

Built the application locally (npm run build) and ran it on static server and it was working absolutely fine.
Here is my script from package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "serve -s build",
    "local": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --transformIgnorePatterns"
  }
```

I have these in my yaml file

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 1.0
  disk_size_gb: 5

network:
  session_affinity: true

env_variables:
 This has backend deployed url
  
handlers:
  - url: /(.*\..+)$
    static_files: build/\1
  - url: /.*
    static_files: build/index.html
```

I'm able to access my backend url which is deployed on gcp. It's just the issue with frontend. When I switch back to my old react and CRA-ts version and deploy, it works fine. Not sure what's going wrong after upgrading to new react version.

Tried to find nginx folder in /usr/local/nginx/conf, /etc/nginx and /usr/local/etc/nginx. But there was nothing in there. Is there anything I'm still missing?

Comment: it sounds like you're missing an nginx config

Comment: Alex, when I deploy old version of react I did not have to make any changes for nginx config. Also I don't think I have used it anytime during deployment. Do I have to make one or is there any default file? I tried to check nginx file but was not able to find any file there.

Comment: How are you running nginx/ any of this? What software is that yaml file for?

Comment: My node app is configured using yaml file in App engine and I use `gcloud app deploy ./file.yaml` command for deploying the app.

Comment: Hi there, did you find your solution? I just encountered the same issue today but just for certain pages of my app.

Comment: I had to create nginx.conf file, configured my Docker file accordingly with nginx settings and then deployed my app.